# Can't login to Admin panel of Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel, admin-login

I have been doing development on Magento 2 since couple of months and suddenly my Admin panel stopped logging in and gives following error

```
a:4:{i:0;s:70:"Class Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\Role\GroupFactory does not exist";i:1;s:6145:"#0 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Authori...')
#1 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Authori...')
#2 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Authori...')
#3 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Authori...')
#4 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'roleLoader', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#5 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#7 /var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('\\Magento\\Framew...')
#8 /var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->_getSubject()
#9 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(221): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()
#10 /var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(102): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()
#11 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(156): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->processLogin()
#12 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('demo', 'demo1234')
#13 /var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(78): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('demo', 'demo1234')
#15 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#19 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#26 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#29 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#31 /var/www/html/Magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#32 {main}";s:3:"url";s:102:"/Magento/admin/admin/index/index/key/90e6d1a675a5403c95c9b99ef4b31af5b275b23a49a6b48136ad244e25b596bc/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/Magento/index.php";}
```

What is the issue and why can't I login?

Answer (score 4):

Delete your **var/generation , var/cache , var/page_cache** folder.

After that run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** command.

It will compile and generate the factory class and depended proxy classes.

Lastly clear the cache by **php bin/magento cache:clean** command

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what was the issue but after deleting content of var/generation folder, it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my solution was to remove all site data/cookies from chrome.

See how to do that here [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies)

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was incorrect file permissions.
the solution:

```
# chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www
```

problem solved immediately

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have clues, you may try below commands.

```
rm -r pub/static/**/*
rm -r generated/**/*
rm -r var/view_preprocessed/**/*
php bin/magento c:f
```

If you've messed up with permissions, try below commands

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find var/ pub/static pub/media app/etc generated/ -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var/ pub/static pub/media app/etc generated/ -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chmod 640 app/etc/env.php
chmod -R g+s .
```